# How to enqueue Bootstrap 4.6 js & css from local files

Tags: functions, twitter-bootstrap, local-installation

I currently have Bootstrap 4.6 `js` and `css` loading from Bootstrap CDNs in WordPress via `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` respectively in the `functions.php` file

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.6.0', true);
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.6.0', 'all' );
```

BUT I would like to source both these files from downloaded resources

Unfortunately I don't have enough knowledge to be certain of writing these enqueue instructions correctly _  The source address is not so much the problem,  I'm specifically seeking help on how to complete the `array` element of the code-line, and any other additions that might be required:

JS - `array( 'jquery' ), '4.6.0', true);` and CSS - `array(), '4.6.0', 'all' );`

Thanks in advance for any advice

Answer (score 0):

This answer was given on the main StackOverflow platform

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.6.0', true);
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.6.0', 'all' );
```

The supplied code has been tested and works as expected

Comment: Apart from the actual path to the Bootstrap source files_ no other changes to the original code were required